# Dynamic Bootstrap Popover Content

Tags: java, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, append, popover

I have a link that is toggling a Bootstrap Popover:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="List of Stuff" data-rights="${result.itemId}">Toggle Popover</a>
```

Now on the back end, result.itemId contains a list of countries that I need to display in the popover.  I have the popover call, and a for loop to list out all of the countries associated with result.itemId PLUS a console.log that is properly displaying all of the countries in the console, I just don't know how to have them display properly in the popover.

Here's my Javascript:

```
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    html: true,
    content: function(){
        var rights = $(this).data('rights');
        var countries = resultsCountries[rights];
        for (var i in countries) {
            $(".popover-content").append('<span>' + i + ' &ndash; ' + countries[i] + '<span/><br/>');
            console.log(i, countries[i]);
        }
    }
  })
})
```

Like I said, in the console, all of the countries that associated with this result.itemId are displaying as they should, so I am able to access the database the countries are stored in, I just don't know how to get them to display in the popover "popover-content".

I should add, that this is dynamic, so depending on the result.itemId, the content of the popover would be different.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: then why is the console displaying the countries associated with the result.itemId?

Comment: We are missing a lot of code but I'd say: 1) When you get you countries from the back end, directly plus them in the popover and 
2) at the bottom of the html add : 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();   
});
</script>

Comment: it displays the countries because they sure are contained in resultCountries[rights] but still you are not showing us how you get them. you are trying to fill the popover and initialize it at the same time.

Comment: why does "how I get the data" affect how I want it displayed? I am getting the data, the console.log is showing exactly that the data is coming in as I need it to be, I just need to properly display it. How do I properly display it?

Comment: Hm I think you should try to read the previous comments, the answer is written, it's up to you to accept it or not. I'll try to be more clear.

As long as you keep trying to initialize and fill your popover at the same time it will definitely not work, even if you would like to. If you can understand that you need to create the popover first, and then initialize it when the document is ready, you should get it to work. 

Try to read my previous comment again if you don't get it. Good Luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return your elements in the content function (by adding spans to the variable on each iteration).

Here is an example:

```
$(function() {

  var resultCountries = ['Germany', 'France', 'Spain'];

  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    html: true,
    content: function() {
      var result = $();
      for (var i in resultCountries) {
        result = result.add(('<span>' + i + ' &ndash; ' + resultCountries[i] + '<span/><br/>'));
        console.log(i, resultCountries[i]);
      }
      return result;
    }

  });

});
```

### [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/MbPjzV)

Comment: yeah, I found out that I needed to have a string variable, and then add to that variable every iteration, then return that variable at the end.  Thank you @makshh

Answer (score 2):

So... aside from being told, in so many words *"that's just the way it is"*, I continued to dig, and lo and behold, the answer presented itself.

```
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    html: true,
    placement: 'auto right',
    content: function(){
        var rights = $(this).data('rights');
        var content = "";
        var countries = resultsCountries[rights];
        for (var i in countries) {
            content += '<span>' + i + ' &ndash; ' + countries[i] + '<span/><br/>';
        }
        return content;
    }
  })
})
```

I saw in several other issues where folks wanted to set their content dynamically, they would always have a return at the end, and THAT would populate the popover properly.  The append was also an issue.  instead, I set a string variable "content", and then simple += more content through the loop.

The result is exactly as desired, the user clicks the link, and the popover appears displaying the countries associated with the result.itemId.